# Save state of List<Integer>

Tags: java, android

I created a puzzle-game in which tiles can be shuffled to recreate an image. The app is nearly finished except for the part where I save the data so the game can be continued when the app is restarted. I found some information about SharedPreferences, but I understand it's not possible to save a List with it. I have an Integer List with the indices of the puzzle-pieces, which needs to be saved. I tried converting the List to a string and retrieving that, but it went bad and messed up my whole program. I'm not skilled enough to fix it, so I am reaching out to you. My question therefore is, how do I save my List of integers?

Sorry in advance if the question has been asked before, I have been looking on the internet for over two hours and I really need some help. :)

Comment: Use a csv String, save it, then use the comma to break apart your String into proper ints when you restore it.

Comment: I tried this, but my program threw an error when it tried to access the newly created List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to convert to a `String`, and then put it in `SharedPreferences`. You can convert the `List` to a `String` like this:

```
public static String listIntToString(List<Integer> list) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i: list)
        s.append(i).append(" ");
    return s.toString();
}
```

Now to get back to a `List<Integer>`:

```
public static List<Integer> stringToListInt(String s) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
    while (scan.hasNextInt())
        result.add(scan.nextInt());
    scan.close();
    return result;
}
```

This is much cleaner than messing about with files or databases or XML for something so simple.

---

Actually if you want to get cute then you can just convert the `List<Integer>` to a `String` using its `.toString()` method, and then use this to get back to the `List<Integer>`:

```
public static List<Integer> defaultStringToListInt(String s) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
    scan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[, \\[\\]]+"));
    while (scan.hasNextInt())
        result.add(scan.nextInt());
    scan.close();
    return result;
}
```

That way, you only have to define one helper method. This works because the `.toString()` method on a `List<Integer>` comes out as something like

```
[1, 22, -3, 4, 5]
```

and the code above scans through looking for integers, using square brackets, commas and spaces as delimiters.

Comment: I tried this, but it throws a NullPointerException "attempt to get length of null array", so I am doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: @Nifty on which line? The code I gave you doesn't use any arrays...

Comment: You're right, it's something I did wrong. I'm fixing it now and hope it works, thanks for the answer though! I think this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a database to store information that your app will retrieve when it restarts or (probably the easier method) is to save your list of integers to a file and read from it when your app restarts.

Comment: So what method is preferred? I find it hard to make a choice because I'm not familiar with one of them.

Comment: I'd use the save to file method.

Comment: Actually I take that back. Read up about SQLite. that might be the better way

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an XML, and then reading it to gather your data each time your app starts. You could do something like the following to write your XML;

```
// Create your document and it's root element.
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.newDocument();
Element root = doc.createElement("root");
doc.appendChild(root);
// Loop through your list and create an xml element for each list element.
for(Integer i : yourList){
     Element listItem = doc.createElement("integer");       
     listItem.setAttribute("value", i.toString());
     root.appendChild(listItem);
}
// write the the Document to where-ever you want.
FileOutputStream fos = yourContext.openFileOutput("data_store.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
TransformerFactory factory = new TransformerFactory();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(root);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fos);
transformer(source, result);
```

And to read your XML simply;

```
FileInputStream fis = yourContext.openFileInput("data_store.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(fis);
// Get & loop through a list of all integer elements
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("integer");
for(Node n : nodes){
    if(n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
        Element e = (Element) n;
        yourList.add(Integer.parseInt(e.getAttribute("value")));
    }        
}
```

Although the above is a little overkill, you may find yourself wanting to store other related details, in which case this solution is much more extensible. I hope this helps.

Further reading;

- [Java DOM tutorial.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html)
- [Android Transformer API](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html)